# Can someone explain this proof of the relationship between chromatic number and independence number to me?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, permutations

I came across the following claim and proof in [this paper,](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/papers/hbk94.pdf) and I really don't follow.

If $G$ is a vertex-transitive graph with independence number $\alpha$ and chromatic number $\chi$ then

$n/α(G) ≤ χ(G) ≤ n(1 + ln(n))/α(G)$

Proof (of the rightmost inequality): Let $A$ be an independent set of size $α = α(G)$; then
the probability that $m = ⌈ln(n)⌉$ random translates of $A$ (by automorphisms) do not cover
$V(G)$ is less than $n · (1 − α/n)^m < n · e^{−αm/n} ≤ 1$.

More specifically, I don't understand where the chromatic number comes into it, or why the final inequality leads to something of the form $n(1 + ln(n))/α(G)$. I understand the meaning of vertex transitivity, and both $\alpha$ and $\chi$, but the logic of the proof itself doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I think $m$ should be $\frac{n}{\alpha} \left\lceil \ln n \right\rceil$ in this proof.

Answer (score 2):

Since the probability that $m$ random translates of $A$ by automorphisms do not cover $V(G)$ is less than $1$, there must be some cover of $V(G)$ by $m$ translates of $A$. Each translate of $A$ is an independent set, so each translate of $A$ has chromatic number $1$, and it follows that

$$\chi(G)\le m=\lceil\ln n\rceil<1+\ln n\le(1+\ln n)\frac{n}{\alpha(G)}\;,$$

since clearly $\alpha(G)\le n$ and therefore $\frac{n}{\alpha(G)}\le 1$.